# update multidimensional arrays in postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array

```
  id        Weather

   1    {{KS,'S'},{MO,'S'},{CA,'S'}}
```

I am trying to update 'S' to 'W' for all KS,MO,CA.

I am executing below query and it is throwing me an error

```
 UPDATE table
 SET Weather[][2] ='W' where id=1;
```

expected output

```
  id        Weather

   1    {{KS,'W'},{MO,'W'},{CA,'W'}}
```

Comment: Normalize your data model would be a much better solution. Or at least switch to a `jsonb` column where this kind of structured information can be stored more elegantly

Comment: Is there any alternative with out normalizing data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is possible using ordinary `UPDATE`.
Let's try to select items what we need to replace:

```
-- first, second and third item from array and convert to string
SELECT array_to_string(weather[1:1], ',') AS KS,
       array_to_string(weather[2:2], ',') AS MO,
       array_to_string(weather[3:3], ',') AS CA
FROM test_tbl;
```

Result: `"KS,'S'","MO,'S'","CA,'S'"`

Now we can select records records for update using just comparing string with array item(as string):

```
SELECT * FROM test_tbl
-- KS,'S'
WHERE array_to_string(weather[1:1], ',') = concat('KS,', quote_literal('S'))
-- MO,'S'
-- array_to_string(weather[2:2], ',') = concat('MO,', quote_literal('S'))
-- CA,'S'
-- array_to_string(weather[3:3], ',') = concat('CA,', quote_literal('S'))
```

Ok. Now we need just to merge array by parts with a new item.

```
UPDATE test_tbl
--  generate first item + other items
SET weather = string_to_array(concat('KS,', quote_literal('W')), ',')::varchar[] || weather[2:]
WHERE array_to_string(weather[1:1], ',') = concat('KS,', quote_literal('S'));

UPDATE test_tbl
-- first item + generate second + other items
SET weather = weather[1:1] || string_to_array(concat('MO,', quote_literal('W')), ',')::varchar[] || weather[3:]
WHERE array_to_string(weather[2:2], ',') = concat('MO,', quote_literal('S'));

UPDATE test_tbl
-- first + second items, generate third + other items
SET weather = weather[0:2] || string_to_array(concat('CA,', quote_literal('W')), ',')::varchar[] || weather[4:]
WHERE array_to_string(weather[3:3], ',') = concat('CA,', quote_literal('S'));
```

Result: `{{KS,'W'},{MO,'W'},{CA,'W'}}`. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I believe that normalizing your data would be the best solution, but if it is not an option for you, try this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change_array(p TEXT[][]) RETURNS TEXT[][] AS $$
DECLARE row record; res TEXT[][]; 
DECLARE i INT :=0;
BEGIN
   LOOP 
     EXIT WHEN i = array_length(p,1);
     i:=i+1;
       IF p[i:i][1:2] <@ ARRAY[['KS','S']] THEN
         res := res || ARRAY[['KS','W']];
       ELSEIF p[i:i][1:2] <@ ARRAY[['MO','S']] THEN
     res := res || ARRAY[['MO','W']];
       ELSEIF p[i:i][1:2] <@ ARRAY[['CA','S']] THEN
     res := res || ARRAY[['CA','W']];
       ELSE res := res || p[i:i];
       END IF;
   END LOOP;  
  RETURN res;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

Testing with your example..

```
SELECT change_array(ARRAY[['KS','S'],['MO','S'],['CA','S'],['XX','S']]);
         change_array          
-------------------------------
 {{KS,W},{MO,W},{CA,W},{XX,S}}

(1 Zeile)
```